Microsoft Entra IDP signing assertion with expired certificate?
We have a web application, and some clients ask us to setup SSO for them. We use SAML and register as a Service Provider, with most of our clients using Entra/AzureAD as an Identity Provider. In order to do that, they provide us with:

an entity ID, like https://sts.windows.net/xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx/
an SSO/SLS URL
an x509 certificate, which can be used to verify the signature of their SAML messages

I have realized yesterday that the certificate for one client has been expired for 15 days, yet this is not posing any issue. He still uses SSO without any trouble. Upon checking, I've determined that the SAML Auth messages we receive from this client are still being signed using the expired certificate
Hence my questions:

Is it a security issue that our SSO library does not check the expiration date for the certificate? (we are using a library based on OneLogin which seems to be quite the standard)
Why is my client's Entra still sending messages signed with an expired certificate? When I check their IDP metadata (at https://sts.windows.net/xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml), it lists 5 certificates for signing (which are all valid), but for some reason these are not the ones being used in the messages I receive

As I don't have access to an Entra/AzureAD admin console myself, it's quite difficult to understand how that works on their end
Thanks!

Have you reviewed the configuration of the software that you are using?  https://github.com/SAML-Toolkits/php-saml?tab=readme-ov-file#security-warning "In production, the strict parameter MUST be set as "true" and the signatureAlgorithm and digestAlgorithm under security must be set to something other than SHA1. Otherwise your environment is not secure and will be exposed to attacks. In production also we highly recommended to register on the settings the IdP certificate instead of using the fingerprint method."

https://github.com/SAML-Toolkits/php-saml/blob/master/settings_example.php

Yes, we are using strict mode, and digging into the code of the library, it seems to me that there is never any attempt to check for certificate expiration, which is weird. What surprises me more, though, is Entra/AzureAD allowing to sign assertions with an expired certificate


Is it a security issue that our SSO library does not check the expiration date for the certificate?

No, as it's not really used as a certificate in the first place.
The SAML certificate doesn't have any "expiring" information – unlike its TLS counterparts it doesn't certify the binding between a domain name and key holder, but is only used as a container for the public key, and whatever name it might have is completely ignored.
Likewise the issuer chain is also normally ignored (most SAML certificates are self-issued, again because they don't really certify anything); the public key gets its trust from being listed in the SAML metadata (and other means are used to distribute metadata securely, such as a completely separate "metadata feed signing" certificate). Revocation therefore relies on the metadata itself being updated, rather than any external CRL, so expiry to keep CRLs short is also not relevant.
I believe this is actually required behavior in some of the usual SAML "profiles", such as the one followed by eduGain.
It's very much like an SSH public key in known_hosts in that sense.

Why is my client's Entra still sending messages signed with an expired certificate?

Difficult to tell from here, but my guess is that one of those new certificates might have the same public key as the expired one.

Thank you @grawity - "Revocation therefore relies on the metadata itself being updated" what you mean by that is that my SP should only ever trust the certificates listed in the IDP's metadata, I guess?
In my case, the IDP still uses the old expired certificate to sign the assertions (I've checked the payload of the certificate that's included in the assertion and it's indeed expired).

Did you check the public keys of both those certificates? Are they different?

The federation metadata for this client exposes 5 certificates, all of which are valid and have a unique public key. The assertions we receive from this client's IDP, though, are signed with an expired certificate (whose public key doesn't match any of those published in the metadata). I suspect maybe there is a setting in AzureAD/Entra where one can choose to use a custom certificate for a specific SAML app, rather than the federation's certificates?
